# passing a command line argument into RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

In ruby how do you pass in a variable to use in Rspec.configure via the command line? if I try something like `env SETUP=blah rspec spec/debug_spec.rb` I will get the error  `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant SETUP (NameError)`. I get the same outcome attempting to get the value with `temp = SETUP` and `temp = ENV[SETUP]` in Rspec configure. I want to use this variable to guide how a number of global variables are setup. Something like tags is not suitable in my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you're just missing the quotes for the string (that's why you get the `NameError` exception), so

If your command line is like this:

```
SETUP=blah rspec spec/debug_spec.rb
```

The in your `spec_helper.rb`, you would use it like this:

```
temp = ENV['SETUP']
```

Comment: `SETUP=blah rspec spec/debug_spec.rb:12` can not execute by specific line number. Please advise.